# python coverage error during html report (NoSource: No source for code:)

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, python-unittest, coverage.py

I encounter the following error during reporting html coverage.

```
myrepo>coverage report html
html   NoSource: No source for code: 'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\html': [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\usr\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\html'
Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------
No data to report.
```

---

**However**, the directory exists, and I have permission for that:

```
myrepo>ls -la C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\html
total 172
drwxr-xr-x 1 usr 197121     0 Nov 26  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 usr 197121     0 Nov 26  2018 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 197121  4888 Oct 20  2018 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 usr 197121     0 Nov 26  2018 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 197121 77824 Oct 20  2018 entities.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 197121 18191 Oct 20  2018 parser.py
```

Note, that I can print coverage report in terminal:

```
myrepo>coverage report
Name                               Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------
tests\PexpectTestCase.py              46     18    61%
tests\__init__.py                      2      0   100%
tests\test_command_list_split.py      18      1    94%
tests\test_constructor.py             18      1    94%
tests\test_delay.py                   25      0   100%
tests\test_destructor.py              56      2    96%
wexpect.py                          1401    819    42%
------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                               1566    841    46%
```

---

**How can I generate html report?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate an HTML report with `coverage html`.